# How to commute a string in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I'm new in `python` and while I was coding a little program I found a problem,

starting with a string like:

```
string = ('hello!')
```

I need to get a list like:

```
list = ['h','e','l','l','o','!']
```

How can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  It is called comprehension.

```
[i for i in strng]
```

Result:

```
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '!']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
s = 'hello!'

l = list(s)
print(l)
```

**output**

```
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '!']
```